# My search input and pagination aren't triggering anything in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to react.
My search input and pagination buttons aren't triggering anything and nothing comes up in the console, what is wrong with my code ?

I tried putting every functions in `App.js` to get it cleaner.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from './List';

let API = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      results: [],
      search: '',
      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 3
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.updateSearch = this.updateSearch.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API);
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ results: json.results });
  };

  handleClick(event) {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  }

  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ 
      search: event.target.value.substr(0, 20) 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List data={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

List.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Person from './Person';

class List extends Component {
    render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    const { results, search, updateSearch, handleClick, currentPage, todosPerPage } = data;
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo).filter(item => {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1;
    });

    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((item, number) => {
      return (
        <Person item={item} key={number} />
      );
    });

    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(results.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <li className="page-link" key={number} id={number} onClick={handleClick} style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>{number}</li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="flex-grow-1">
        <h1>Personnages de Star Wars</h1>
        <form className="mb-4">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Rechercher</label>
            <input 
            className="form-control" 
            type="text"
            placeholder="luke skywalker..."
            value={search}
            onChange={updateSearch}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div className="row mb-5">{renderTodos}</div>
        <nav aria-label="Navigation">
          <ul id="page-number" className="pagination justify-content-center">{renderPageNumbers}</ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default List;
```

The value of the input doesn't change one bit if I type in it and if I right click on a page number, the console gets me `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '#4' is not a valid selector.`

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in the `List` class you attempt take `updateSearch` and `handleClick` out of `data` (which in turn comes from `this.props`). But `updateSearch` and `handleClick` are never placed inside `data`. If you log either of these methods to the console you'll see they are undefined.

To fix this, you need to pass `updateSearch` and `handleClick` from `App` to `List`. You can do this either by including the methods inside the `data` prop, or by passing them directly as their own props (which I would recommend).

For example, you can change the `render` method of `App` to look something like this:

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List
          data={this.state}
          updateSearch={ this.updateSearch }
          handleClick={ this.handleClick }
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Then in the `render` method of `List` you can do this:

```js
const { data, updateSearch, handleClick } = this.props;
```

and remove the definitions of the two methods from the destructuring of `data` below.